# Multi-language usability question

Tags: internationalisation

We have a small tourist business (some apartments and a restaurant). On the website, we declares that we speak a number of languages, and we have also translated the site into some languages.

Is the design we choose 'correct' or is it hard to grasp and how would you improve it?

[image: Languages]

On the left the languages that we speak, on the right the multi-language sites.

PS. We choose not to uses flags as loads of nations speak English, Spanish or even Dutch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the left list is not a menu, it has no links, in which case **I don't think it is a usable design**: the list of languages you speak is formated like the language selector on the right and is also in the same contextual space, this **gives the impression that the languages you state you speak are actually links to select the language of the web, which aren't. The user can feel frustrated.**

I would recommend separating both elements: leave the language selector where it is (or on the left side) and the languages you speak with the contact information and/or the 'about' section.

Comment: That's a great piece of speedy advice.

Answer (score 3):

In your current design the phrases look like clickable links. I agree with Naoise that this can be quite confusing and frustrating.

It 'd be interesting to experiment a bit with different content. Instead of telling something about *you* ('we spreken Nederlands'), try addressing the user directly ('U bent van harte welkom! Goede reis en eet smakelijk!'). I think (but would have to test this to be sure) that a direct message in their own language grabs their attention better than an informative statement.

Comment: I changed the layout. The text is now somewhere else on the page, so that takes care of the confusion. A direct message to the user is a nice touch, but I'm not sure whether that would create more clutter. Bedankt overigens :-)